# os.listdir can't see my directory

Tags: python, windows, windows-8.1

I am working on a python script that installs an 802.1x certificate on a Windows 8.1 machine. This script works fine on Windows 8 and Windows XP (haven't tried it on other machines).

I have isolated the issue. It has to do with clearing out the folder

```
"C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptURLCache\Content"
```

The problem is that I am using the module os and the command listdir on this folder to delete each file in it. However, listdir errors, saying the folder does not exist, when it does indeed exist.

The issue seems to be that `os.listdir` cannot see the LocalLow folder. If I make a two line script:

```
import os

os.listdir("C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData")
```

It shows the following result:

```
['Local', 'Roaming']
```

As you can see, *LocalLow* is missing.

I thought it might be a permissions issue, but I am having serious trouble figuring out what a next step might be. I am running the process as an administrator from the command line, and it simply doesn't see the folder.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: changing the string to r"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData", "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData", or C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/AppData" all produce identical results

Edit: Another unusual wrinkle in this issue: If I manually create a new directory in that location I am unable to see it through os.listdir either. In addition, I cannot browse to the LocalLow or my New Folder through the "Save As.." command in Notepad++

I'm starting to think this is a bug in Windows 8.1 preview.

Comment: You say "... when it does indeed exist.", but the evidence you show seems to indicate that it does not. Why do you think it does exist?

Comment: If you fire up cmd or powershell and try to list the contents of the `AppData` directory, do you see `LocalLow`? Also, maybe you do `os.walk(directory)` and see if you get the same results?

Comment: Yes, both ls and simply browsing to the folder let me see it just fine. I can also cd into it from a cmd prompt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I encountered this issue recently.

I found it's caused by [Windows file system redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

and you can check out following python snippet

```
import ctypes

class disable_file_system_redirection:
    _disable = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
    _revert = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_value = ctypes.c_long()
        self.success = self._disable(ctypes.byref(self.old_value))
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.success:
            self._revert(self.old_value)


#Example usage
import os

path = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData'

print os.listdir(path)
with disable_file_system_redirection():
    print os.listdir(path)
print os.listdir(path)
```

ref : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578035-disable-file-system-redirector/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. This looks good, but unfortunately, I am no longer at the job where I was working with python, so I can't confirm that this works. If anyone else can confirm it, I will be glad to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @JasonBray worked for me, though if you're running python 3.x+ you need `print(os.listdir(path))` instead of `print os.listdir(path)`

Comment: I wish I could give this more upvotes. I spent hours banging my head against the wall with this, where a newly-created directory in C:\Windows\System32 appeared to not exist as far as Python was concerned. @JasonBray - this works and should definitely be marked as the answer. Kudos to adamLee.

Answer (score 5):

You must have escape sequences in your path.  You should use a raw string for file/directory paths:

```
# By putting the 'r' at the start, I make this string a raw string
# Raw strings do not process escape sequences
r"C:\path\to\file"
```

or put the slashes the other way:

```
"C:/path/to/file"
```

or escape the slashes:

```
# You probably won't want this method because it makes your paths huge
# I just listed it because it *does* work
"C:\\path\\to\\file"
```

Comment: Another option is to use double backslashes in the path (i.e. '\\' instead of '\')

Comment: @JeffBridgman - I was just typing that when you commented. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! However, all three options produce exactly the same results as my original script

Comment: Okay, I have constructed a workaround by launching a subprocess that runs a batch file to delete them. I had to modify the attributes of the files in each folder, which I'm not sure, but might be related to why the os module is unable to see that folder.

Comment: @iCodez On the first two paths you don't have a closing `"`, is that not required? Or was that just a typo? I'm not terribly familiar with python.

Comment: @JeffBridgman - No, those were actually typos.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious as to how you are able to list the contents with those two lines. You are using escape sequences \W, \S, \c, \s, \A in your code. Try escaping the back slash like this:

```
import os
os.listdir('C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData')
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why those are not being interpreted as escape sequences, but all three of the suggestions made above, as well as the original code work exactly the same